# Adding using input for file name into a file path during loading

Tags: string, path, load, filenames, user-input

I am trying to ask the user to input a few strings of information that will ultimately determine the path used to load a file. For example I've got a few sections A,B,C and a few groups A,B in each of the sections.

So if the user is in Section A group B the program will ask

section=input('Please enter your section letter(A,B or C): ','s')
group=input('Please enter your group letter(A or B): ','s')

The user will input A and B respectively

The file that needs to load is corresponding to the path name
'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Workshop 4\Section_A\Group_B\Input_Data\ws4FOAM.lvm'

```
       ^^      ^^
```

this is what I tried but didn't work

load ('C:\Users\User\Desktop\Workshop 4\Section_%d\Group_%d\Input_Data\ws4FOAM.lvm',section,group);

Thanks

Comment: Display the string somehow before attempting to load it -- make sure it's actually the string you want. Also, what language is this? Do you need to worry about escape characters in your file path string, with all those backslashes?  Does it matter whether the input is upper or lowercase? (You might need to convert it if it does.)

Comment: Yes, please tag this question with the relevant languages you are using.